Why my vscode running two typescript for type checking?
Why my vscode is running two typescript in background, which will make every error reported twice.(Don't know what informations are helpful, please add a comment to tell me and I will post them)

Every error is reported twice

In the status bar at the bottom, I can see two typescript is working

In output channel, I can also see two typescript is working
the first one

the second one


